# Sage theme build error: Invalid UTF-8 at runLoaders

Tags: wordpress, webpack, encoding, utf-8, roots-sage

I was building a theme with sage and copy the folder to another location. After that when I try to build the project I get this error:

> Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Invalid UTF-8
>       at runLoaders (/var/www/html/plataforma/wp-content/themes/template-mnm/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:195:19)
>       at /var/www/html/plataforma/wp-content/themes/template-mnm/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:364:11
>       at /var/www/html/plataforma/wp-content/themes/template-mnm/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:230:18
>       at context.callback (/var/www/html/plataforma/wp-content/themes/template-mnm/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
>       at Object.asyncSassJobQueue.push [as callback] (/var/www/html/plataforma/wp-content/themes/template-mnm/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:55:13)
>       at Object. (/var/www/html/plataforma/wp-content/themes/template-mnm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2244:31)
>       at Object.callback (/var/www/html/plataforma/wp-content/themes/template-mnm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16)
>       at options.error (/var/www/html/plataforma/wp-content/themes/template-mnm/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:294:32)
>
> @ multi ./scripts/main.js ./styles/main.scss
>
> error  in ./resources/assets/styles/main.scss
>
> Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Invalid UTF-8
>       at runLoaders (/var/www/html/plataforma/wp-content/themes/template-mnm/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:195:19)
>       at /var/www/html/plataforma/wp-content/themes/template-mnm/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:364:11
>       at /var/www/html/plataforma/wp-content/themes/template-mnm/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:230:18
>       at context.callback (/var/www/html/plataforma/wp-content/themes/template-mnm/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
>       at Object.asyncSassJobQueue.push [as callback] (/var/www/html/plataforma/wp-content/themes/template-mnm/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:55:13)
>       at Object. (/var/www/html/plataforma/wp-content/themes/template-mnm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2244:31)
>       at Object.callback (/var/www/html/plataforma/wp-content/themes/template-mnm/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16)
>       at options.error (/var/www/html/plataforma/wp-content/themes/template-mnm/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:294:32)

I think the encoding of the files have changed, is there a way to correct the problem?

I really apreciate any help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I've found the answer and I will post it in case anyone has the same problem. The things was one of the scss files imported inside main.scss had the wrong encoding.
Saving the file with the correct encoding solved the problem.